# WTForms, how to attach JSON data to the request

Tags: ajax, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms, wtforms-json

I'm bulding a form with WTForms for a Flask application.
This form's las field is an address field that works with google PlacesAPI, so it autocompletes the address the user is introducing in that field.

I want to be able to save all the data this PlacesAPI generates when the user selects an address, but I'm struggling to find a proper way to send that data to the server.

I have a Flask with MongoDB as backend.

**What I have tried**

1. AJAX

I submited the form with Jquery Ajax method, I validated it by adding WTF-JSON to my project, it monkeypatches the Form class and some methods so it can process JSON as ***kwargs.

**Problem**: this leaves me without being able to easily redirect the user on form validation.

2. Adding hidden input field

I can add a hidden input field where I add all the address JSON as a string and then process it in my backend

**Problem**: Somehow this simes hacky, I was wondering if there is a better way

**Question**

What would be the right way to do this? It's the first time I've tried, so I'm pretty sure there must be a way I'm missing here. Thanks a lot for all your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option # 1 is the best option considering the scenarios you have explained. There should not be any problems in re-directing the user to form validation page as you can manage it through XHR. Here is what I can suggest

```
@catalog.route('/')
@catalog.route('/your_page')
def home():
    if request.is_xhr:
        ## Here you can call the def and store the addresses
        addresses = Address.query.all() 
        json_addresses jsonify({'addresses': addresses)})
        return render_template('your_form_page.html', json_addresses)
```

While rendering the template page you pass few more parameters such as validation messages.

Please use `is_xhr` as per the need of your functionality but I recommend it.

Comment: Thanks Pralhad, I have done that and I ran into a CSRF validation problem. I have explained it [here](http://www.reddit.com/r/flask/comments/3afaiv/af_flaskwtf_send_json_data_and_csrf_validation/) for I didin't want to polute this question with that problem. Should I open a new thread or explain my probem here?

Comment: Glad to know that - you have already resolved it. Its really upto you - but I would suggest to explain the things here only  instead a new thread :)

Comment: Well, my problem is the following : I have a form that requires an address field. I'm using the Google places API to auto load suggestions and I need to send that API data for the input place to the database as well. I did it with ajax, using is_xhr, your suggest is how I tend to handle this kind of situation. The thing is I send all the information using jquery with an ajax post request, and processes the validity of the for using wtforms-json package (form=My orm.from_json(request.json). It works flawlessly, except that It doesn't when I turn csrf protection with flask wtforms.

Comment: I have correctly added the csrf token to my headers, and I'm inheriting from the flask wtforms Form object, not the wtforms Form object. My only idea is that maybe wtforms-json does something to the class when it monkey patches it. Maybe that's messing with the validation.